# Defining routes for all my actions and controllers in ASP.NET MVC route collection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I am bit new to Routing in ASP.NET MVC. I am building a project with multiple controllers and multiple actions. However, I wonder if I have to define a new route to the route collection for each action of each controller?.
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you start by working through some tutorials and documemtation, for example [ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) and [MVC Controllers and Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing) and [ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). You only need to define specific routes when the default route will not meet your needs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about best practices and programming theory. This is a better fit for Programmers.StackExchange, but this question still needs some cleanup before it can be "on-topic" there, as well.

Comment: I don't agree, OP is asking if they have to define routes for each action of each controller.  Great question, as the route-to-controller matching logic seems magical to us beginners!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if I have to define a new route to the route collection for
>   each action of each controller?

No, You do not **have to** define a new route for each action.

> What is the main reason for defining routes for my actions and
>   controller in there if in any case I can request the action and
>   controller via the url even there are not routes defined?

The default route serve the purpose in most of the cases however you will find instances where adding a custom specific route make sense.

Custom routes gives you lot of power especially if you add [route constraints](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299531/Custom-routes-for-MVC-Application).

Refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC) article for in depth details and example.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. however my main concern is what happen if someone type the wrong thing into their browser address the might not be able to invoke either right action or controller. so I am trying to define routes with optional parameters for that. but I don't think this is the properly way to do it. How can I handle it?

Comment: If someone type the wrong URL or try to temper the urls, direct them to error page with "The page you have requested cannot be found". And it will always be the case no matter how many routes you will define.